# parse contents from returned json to el-dropdown-item

Tags: json, vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui

Need help with el-dropdown to parse contents from express parsed json.

Tried https://medium.com/html-all-the-things/hatt-vue-js-2-9b34557f0305 this tutorial and seems there is no option to parse contents from JSON.

```
/*dropdown in index.vue, simplified*/
<el-dropdown>
  <el-button type="primary" trigger="click">dropList<i class="el-icon-arrow-down el-icon--right"></i>
  </el-button>
  <el-dropdown-menu>
    <el-dropdown-item command="someCommandWhichIsNotYetWritten">{{getList}}</el-dropdown-item>
  </el-dropdown-menu>
</el-dropdown>

/*script*/
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    getList: []
   }
}

/*The returning JSON is as follows*/

result {
  metaData: [ { name: 'NAME' } ],
  rows: [
    { NAME: '131' },
    { NAME: '132' },
    { NAME: '138' },
    { NAME: '139' },
    { NAME: '142' },
    { NAME: '193' },
    { NAME: '194' },
    { NAME: '235' },
    { NAME: '241' },
    { NAME: '44' }
  ]
}
```

PS: I know these comment lines doesn't work in all cases. Just added to clarify to what I did.

In this code I see all the contents of JSON, but I want to list those numbers (NAME) individually which connects to a command(a href) or something.
PS: As I understand `el-dropdown command="someCommand"` is similar to `<a href>` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When your data is loaded you need to assign it to a local component data, f. e:
   `this.getList = result.rows`
2. Dropdown items have to be created in a loop (read more about v-for directive in vue docs):
   `<el-dropdown-item @command="todo(item)" v-for="item in getList" :key="item. NAME">{{item.NAME}}</el-dropdown-item>`
3. To handle command from piece of code above you'd have to create local method named todo.